# python basic try catch exception

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

i wrote a code which is dumping numbers which is collected from serial port read as follows:

```
readoff = ser.readline()
```

and the proper format of readoff is follows:

```
a=' 213 -456 725'
```

and then for dumping and making some calculations im splitting it to 3 part and turning them to integer as follows:

```
 splitted=readoff.split()
 if len(splitted) == 3 :    
        temparrayforx.append(int(splitted[0]))
        temparrayfory.append(int(splitted[1]))
        temparrayforz.append(int(splitted[2]))
```

but sometimes from the serial port im reading something like: '2-264' which cannot turned into a integer. or sometimes readoff is not divisible to three.

here is my sample error:

```
temparrayforx.append(int(splitted[0]))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2-264'
```

my goal is if the reading is not correct(if its not 3 part)(if its not a proper number), skip that readoff and go on(read another data). how can i do that ?

thanks for help

Comment: See: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions (googling that might have been faster than writing this question)

Comment: thanks for your help guys. 

when i do try except things its resuming but its also writing the wrong data to array. i want it to forget that serial reading dont write anything and go to next one. how can i do that part. thanks

Comment: Use the right control flow so that it does not append to the list when the exception is raised. Without seeing your code, a solution could be to append to list in the `else` part of the try-except.

Answer (score 5):

The standard python try-catch is:

```
try:
    do_something_risky()

except ExceptionName as exc:
    do_something_else()
```

It is very important to **specify the exceptions you want to catch**, otherwise you might catch unwanted exceptions that should bubble up, resulting in errors difficult to detect.

You can catch different exceptions and react in a different way to them:

```
try:
    do_something_risky()

except SomeException as exc:
    do_this()

except AnotherException as exc:
    do_that()
```

Additionally you can add `else` and `finally`

```
try:
    do_something_risky()

except ExceptionName, AnotherPossibleException as exc:
    do_something_else()

else:
    do_something_when_no_exception_raised()

finally:
    # Useful for cleaning up
    do_something_no_matter_what_happens()
```

### In your case

```
try:
    # Do the problematic thing
except ValueError as exc:
    # Manage the exception
```

Answer (score 3):

You should catch the specific exception that's being raised, ValueError in this case:

```
try:
    temparrayforx.append(int(splitted[0]))
except ValueError as e:
    print e
```

It's important to catch a specific error type so you don't accidentally catch lots of unexpected errors - like if splitted is empty, an IndexError would be raised. A bare 'except:' or 'except Exception:' would hide that from you.

In your case, since you want to catch a couple of different error cases (line doesn't have enough parts, value isn't a number) you can either catch both exception types in the same except clause or have two different except clauses - for example if you need to do different things with each problem.